# replacing a certain word in the text using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a text file that contain paths of some files.
What can I do to replace all the word "original" to "false" using command line or batch scripting ?

**INPUT**

```
C:\original\1\2\3   
C:\original\1\2\4   
C:\original\1\2\5   
C:\original\1\2\36
```

**CHANGED TO**

```
C:\false\1\2\3
C:\false\1\2\4
C:\false\1\2\5
C:\false\1\2\36
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this from a batch file? Can you just open the file in a text editor with a _Find & Replace_ type capability?

Comment: Do you need to do this often, with variable text?  I am presuming this is why you need a batch or command line solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt"|repl "c:\\original\\" "c:\false\" i >"newfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can download third party tools, you can use `sed`. Download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cja5mvymvinmfco/mHw6J4I1Kd)

```
sed -i.bak "s/C:\\original/C:\\replace/" your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in a script named with a ".CMD" extension:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

DEL Output.txt
FOR /F "delims=#" %%H IN ('TYPE InputFile.txt') DO (
        SET LineOut=%%H
        @ECHO !LineOut:\original\=\false\! >> Output.txt
    )
```

Comment: sorry, but this code is not replacing the text  \original\ to \false\ in the file output.txt

Comment: @Sweeper because Solomon missed to *use*  delayed expansion (although he *enabled* it). `@ECHO !LineOut:\original\=\false\! >> Output.txt` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for that help. I just verified it on Windows 10. Not sure what happened originally since I did test it and it did work with the previous syntax (though not sure why since it probably shouldn't have). But I still had the test files on my system, untouched since I posted this answer, and the output was correct. It was probably tested on XP back then, not sure if that makes a difference, but it didn't work this time until I changed the `%` into `!`. Weird. Again, thanks, and I have updated my answer accordingly. :-)

Comment: @Sweeper Stephan was correct. I verified it on Windows 10 and updated my answer with the corrected syntax.